# Automapper ASP.NET CORE mapping custom generic type error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

I have my own generic type: `PagedList<T>`, which is responsible for paging, after I take query from repository and return, for example `PagedList<User>` to service and my service should return `PagedList<UserDTO>`. So I try to map: 
`return _mapper.Map <PagedList<User>, PagedList<UserDTO>>(userList);` and this is what I get:

```
ArgumentException: 
App.Core.Paging.PagedList`1[App.Infrastructure.DTO.UserDTO] needs to have a 
constructor with 0 args or only optional args.
Parameter name: type
lambda_method(Closure , PagedList<User> , PagedList<UserDTO> , 
ResolutionContext )

AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
```

And in my mapper config:
`cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>();` 
Is this enough or am I missing something? Properties in both classes are the same.

Comment: The error tells you the problem, does `UserDTO` have a usable constructor?

Comment: Actually, I should have said `PagedList`...

Comment: @DavidG oh I made empty constructor in PagedList<T> and it worked, whole time I was searching in User/UserDTO. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you the exact problem: The `PagedList` class requires a constructor that AutoMapper can use. The simplest option is to add an empty constructor to the class:

```
public class PagedList<T>
{
    //Add this:
    public PagedList() { }
}
```

However, you will need to determine if that is appropriate for your situation.